# Error 500 executing python script

Tags: python, apache, cgi

I recently re-installed my Ubuntu PC (to 12.04) & had to re-setup apache.
local.domain.com points to localhost (virtual host).
http://local.domain.com/script.py?query=string
script.py is chmod'd to 755.
In my .htaccess I have :

```
Options +ExecCGI
AddHandler cgi-script .py
```

But I get a **500 : Internal Server Error**.
**cat /var/log/apache2/error.domain.com.log** shows nothing.
If I do python script.py in the command line I get :

```
<!-- The above is a description of an error in a Python program, formatted
     for a Web browser because the 'cgitb' module was enabled.  In case you
     are not reading this in a Web browser, here is the original traceback:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 32, in <module>
    queryHash = hashlib.sha224(os.environ['QUERY_STRING']).hexdigest()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'QUERY_STRING'

-->
```

So I don't figure anything wrong with the py script. It used to work before.
But for some reason its not executing in the browser.
What else could I have missed ?

Comment: It looks like Apache is failing to set the `QUERY_STRING` environment variable to the value of the query string in the request.  I'm not an Apache person, so I've no other insight, but perhaps this information is useful to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ubuntu 12.04 has python 2.7. My script's shebang line was :

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.6
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is right there infront of you:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 32, in <module>
    queryHash = hashlib.sha224(os.environ['QUERY_STRING']).hexdigest()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 23, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'QUERY_STRING'
```

Which says it can't access the key `QUERY_STRING`. It even gives you the exact line of code that the error occurred at:

```
File "script.py", line 32
queryHash = hashlib.sha224(os.environ['QUERY_STRING']).hexdigest()
```

The environment variable `QUERY_STRING` has not been set for the apache user. How did you have this set before? You might need to set it in the httpd profile, and for Ubuntu, I'm not sure where that is.

Comment: That error occurs (predictably) when the script is run at the *command line*.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams fair point, should have read more carefully. I'd still recommend setting the env variable locally and testing the script again to diagnose other potential errors with the code. Weird that there's no apache error logging though.

Comment: I do have a error.domain.com.log~. [Sat Jun 30 14:44:08 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] /usr/bin/env: python2.6: No such file or directory
[Sat Jun 30 14:44:08 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Premature end of script headers: script.py